# external library config macro for autoconf/automake

Tags: configuration, autoconf, automake

Is there a autoconf macro to configure generic library that can:

- generates --with configure option
- setup library and include path
- setup compiler/preprocessor and linker flags
- check existence of library and include files
- setup configuration macros

Right now I am doing everything using ARG_WITH, CHECK_LIB, etc. the steps are generic and end up being copy/paste with minor changes. My search the macro archive and did not find generic solution.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly not - it is just awaiting your efforts to publicize your generic code, suitably parameterized (so that you do not end up doing minor changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the complete solution, but you might find `AX_PATH_GENERIC` from the Autoconf Macro Archive useful: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob;f=m4/ax_path_generic.m4